# How to post data using this api url

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, api

I need help in my app so i want to post some data on this api url below :
http://myapiurl.com/myapi/csos.asp?username=asddte&password=erts2&intResortID=7&strpartysurname=test&strpartyfirstname=test&strpartyprefix=M&intqtyadults=1&intqtytotal=1&dtmLine1=20-Mar-2019&strRoomType1=sea&intRooms1=1&intnights1=1&strFlightNo=w&strNotes=FlighDJ76Provide BreakfastHoneymooners&strBookingCode=zx&strPosBookingRef=mine&strPromotionCode=hellogirl@id=22

Can somebody assist me in what C# code i can use

The apiurl above when i put on browser it will insert data to a db and retrun a ID to me so in my app develloped in c# how can i do this to post data or simply excute it"

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myapiurl.com/myapi/csos.asp?username=asddte&password=erts2&intResortID=7&strpartysurname=test&strpartyfirstname=test&strpartyprefix=M&intqtyadults=1&intqtyto");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Can i just use that code above if it okay since all the data that needs to be posted are contain in the url.

Comment: What happened when you tried using that? Did it not work? Why? Some exception? Which?

Comment: Why are username and password in query string?  Also why are you not using https?  Also if you are using a form, why are you using the entire query string rather than the body?

Comment: @Greg the api is was developed using VB so we are connecting to this api to insert data to a DB once it does that it tell the system to trigger emails as well so if run that whole url on browser it does those actions .

Comment: I understand the purpose, does not make it the proper approach to transfer sensitive information though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **HttpClient**

This is available in: .NET Framework 4.5+, .NET Standard 1.1+, .NET Core 1.0+.

In C# you can get it via **[NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http)**

**Including**:

> using System.Net.Http;

It is really recommended to create one HttpClient instance for your application's lifetime and share it. Like this:

> private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

And finally you can send your POST Request via **PostAsync** method from HttpClient:

> var values = new Dictionary {    { "parameter1",
>   "value1" },    { "parameter2", "value2" } };
>
> var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
>
> var response = await
>   client.PostAsync("http://myapiurl.com/myapi/csos.asp", content);
>
> var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

In response you will get a string for example if your api returns string or json.

This is one of many ways to send POST Request to Api. 
You can use also:

**[RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp)**

**[FlurHttp](https://flurl.io/)**

**WebClient**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I have managed to achieve what i wanted to do . Below is the final code :

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myapiurl.com/myapi/csos.asp");
var postData = "username=fdgfdg";
postData += "&password=dfgdg";
postData += "&intResortID=353453";
postData += "&strpartysurname=test";
postData += "&strpartyfirstname=test";
postData += "&strpartyprefix=M";
postData += "&intqtyadults=1";
postData += "&intqtytotal=1";
postData += "&dtmLine1=20-Mar-2019";
postData += "&strRoomType1=sea";
postData += "&intRooms1=1";
postData += "&intnights1=1";
postData += "&strFlightNo=w";
postData += "&strNotes=FlighDJ76";
postData += "&strBookingCode=zx";
postData += "&strPosBookingRef=mine";
postData += "&strPromotionCode=hellogirl";
postData += "&BookID=hgjghjg";

var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);


request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

using (var stream2 = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream2.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var responser = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(responser.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
this.WriteToFile("Some data has been posted  " +responseString);
```

I was using Visual Studio 2008 so cannot use Httpclient . But the code above work fine and it has help me achieve what i want